# Fluorescence Intensity and Fluorescence Quantum Yield

Tags: fluorescence

I plan to use ImageJ to analyze some fluorescence experiments where the pH changes. I will be using fluorescein as the indicator for the pH changes and it will be present in low concentration (like is typically the case when any indicator is used to measure a pH change).

As I understand it, I can get the relative fluorescence intensity from the grayscale intensity in ImageJ.  From the literature I have a chart of relative fluorescence quantum yield for fluorescein versus pH.  If I conduct two experiments, one at pH 12 and another at a lower pH (which is unknown), I think I can determine that lower pH simply from the grayscale intensities in ImageJ and the literature chart that I mentioned.  If the ratio of intensities is equal to the ratio of quantum yields in the literature chart, then I should be able to read the pH from the literature chart.

Assume all conditions for determining the grayscale intensity in ImageJ are identical, except that the pH of the liquid is different. So I'm going to assume that the molar absorptivity, path length, source power and concentration of fluorescein (all ionic and non-ionic forms) remain unchanged. For discussion purposes, let's say the Image J grayscale intensity at a pH of 12 is equal to 100 and at the unknown pH is equal to 60.  The ratio of these intensities is 0.6.  The question is can this ratio of 0.6 be assumed to be equal to the ratio of relative fluorescent quantum yields on the literature chart? So essentially, can a ratio of intensities from ImageJ be considered to be equal to the ratio of quantum yields, under the assumptions that I have outlined, so that I can read the pH from a chart that plots pH versus fluorescence quantum yield.

Comment: +1 Good question. You could search the literature or google to look if any experiment like this has been done before. I am not an expert on this field, but at first glance I think your reasoning is right.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Shoubhik.  I have been searching the literature.  I haven't found a paper that shows a chart of relative intensity versus pH for fluorescein, but I have found a paper that shows charts for fluorophores typically used in biology.  For fluorescein, I've only been able to find a chart that plots quantum yield.

Comment: You must (a) check that the fluorescein absorption and fluorescence quantum yield remain the same as pH is changed and if not correct for this (b) correct for any absorption changes between solutions anyway, i.e. due to dilution etc. (c) Check that intensity scale of you detector is linear, you could use neutral density filters to do this. You reasoning about yields is correct.

Comment: Of course to get the proper intensity ratio you'd need a high pH such that all the fluorescein is unprotonated and a low pH so that all the fluorescein is protonated.

Comment: Fluorescence QY is a measure to be done carefully. Look for article explaining it step by step. After, your logic seems to be correct.

Comment: @porphyrin:  The chart from the literature shows how the fluorescence quantum yield changes with  pH.  Fluorescein can be used as a pH indicator.  Maybe I'm not understanding your point.

Comment: At MaxW:  The plan is to mix NaOH at pH 12 with a 5 or maybe 10% stoichiometric excess of HCL at pH 2 and monitor the fluorescence as mixing proceeds.  The reaction is instantaneous and I'm expecting diffusion controlled mixing. After complete mixing the pH will be of order 3 to 3.5.

I'll also be taking a photo of the base (containing fluorescein) mixing with water and a photo of  the acid (containing fluorescein) mixing with water as "control" images.

Comment: As the fluorescence yield changes with pH the absorption spectrum probably does too as may the emission spectrum (I would guess) so you will need to correct for this change. You also need to measure emission at at the same wavelength in all cases as the detection sensitivity depends on wavelength.